# Is there a way to get facebook response in Json or array format with Facebook PHP SDK V4?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

For example a request like

```
$request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET','/me/accounts?fields=id,name,access_token');
$response = $request->execute();
$arrayResult = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();
print_r($arrayResult);
```

returns

```
Array ( 
    [data] => Array ( 
        [0] => stdClass Object ( 
            [id] => 01010011100001111000111 #it's a fake id 
            [name] => MyAwesomePageName    #And a fake name 
        ) 
    ) 
    [paging] => stdClass Object ( 
        [next] => https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/01010011100001111000111/accounts?fields=id,name&access_token=RanDoMAndFaaKKeEACCessToKen&limit=5000&offset=5000&__after_id=enc_IdOnOTKnoWWhAtThiSIs 
    ) 
)
```

Thats is.
I would like to retrieve all the response in array and without theses stdClass objects.
Just like it was in the previous version of their api.
Thanks.

Comment: No it is not possible

Comment: This is a bug in 4.0 that will be fixed in 4.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Facebook SDK's asArray() method is limited as you've discovered. However, you can manually convert an object to an array using the `get_object_vars( $object );` function. In your example, you can do something like:

```
$array = get_object_vars( $arrayResult['data'][0] );
```

This will convert the page Object into an array. The function isn't recursive, so you'll need to convert each object to an array.

You can use a recursive function like this:

```
function object_to_array($obj) {
    $arr = array();
    if($obj instanceOf GraphObject){
        if(is_scalar($obj->asArray()) ) 
            $arr = $obj->asArray();
        else{
            foreach ($obj->getPropertyNames() as $propName) {
                $arr[$propName] = object_to_array($obj->getProperty($propName));
            }
        }
    }else if(is_array($obj)){
        foreach ($obj as $propKey => $propValue) {
            $arr[$propKey] = object_to_array($obj[$propValue]);
        }
    }else $arr = $obj;
    return $arr;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

An easier way might be to grab the raw JSON from the $response and decode it yourself:

```
$request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me/accounts?fields=id,name,access_token');
$response = $request->execute();
$array = json_decode($response->getRawResponse(), true);
print_r($array);
```

**Update**

As of [PHP SDK 5.0+](https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk) you can use `getDecodedBody()` on the `FacebookResponse` object (this does the JSON decoding for you and returns an array).

```
$fb = new Facebook([...]);
$response = $fb->get('/me', '{access-token}');
$array = $response->getDecodedBody();
```

Comment: i'm using this way and seems to work great. only update is getRawResponse() looks like it's from old spec, as of 5.0 it should now use $response->getBody()

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookResponse/5.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Just use `json_decode($arrayResult)` to get the JSON output.  The output you are getting is simply a php data structure.

Answer (score 0):

We can simply do json_encode and decode as an Array

```
$arrayResult = json_decode(json_encode($appreq['data'][0]),true);
```

## sample output

```
Array
(
[application] => Array
    (
        [name] => Test App
        [namespace] => app-test-app
        [id] => 988798798798
    )
[created_time] => 2015-02-17T08:42:14+0000
[data] => action=acceptit
[from] => Array
    (
        [id] => 987989798
        [name] => TestUser
    )

[message] => I have sent 1 Request
[to] => Array
    (
        [id] => 98098090
        [name] => NameAjax
    )

[id] => 345423452345_34523452453
)
```